# No such property: split for class: java.lang.String

Tags: groovy

I'm facing a Java error but I don't understand why, thats why I post a question here.

I got this error:

> No such property: split for class: java.lang.String

With this code:

```
String cellContent = "[COLUMN columnRef, test]"
cellContent = cellContent.substring(1, cellContent.length() - 1)
String[] splitContent = cellContent.split(', ')
String rowToUse = splitContent[1]
String splitColumn = splitContent[0].split[' ']
String column = splitColumn[1]
```

**Expected result**

```
rowToUse = "test"
column = "columnRef"
```

The error occurred on this line : `String splitColumn = splitContent[0].split[' ']`

Someone has any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not Java (no semicolons). Is it Groovy?

Comment: Yep but I use Java functions thats why I mentionned Java tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
splitContent[0].split[' ']
```

Use roundy brackets for `split`: it's a method invocation:

```
splitContent[0].split(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use round brackets instead of square brackets in:

```
String splitColumn = splitContent[0].split(" ")
```

since you are trying to call a function and not reference an array index.

Comment: This is groovy, single quotes are fine